# Display the table when click the button - jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please advise how to achieve that hide the html inner table when page loading and click the search button, table will display with results only. I don't want to show the empty table. Please see the below code which I have tried.

But sure, after click the button page is getting refresh.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {       

    $("#historylist").hide();

    $("#historysearch").click(function() {
        $("#historylist").show();
    });
    // }
});    

<table id="searchTbl" width="800" >
<tr>
    <td valign="top">Release No</td>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="text" name="releaseNo" value="" style="width:200" />
    </td>
    <td valign="top"><input type="button" value="Search" onClick="commit()" style="width:80" id="historysearch"/></td>
</tr>
<br /><br />

    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="historylist">
    <tr>
        <th><font size="-1">Header1</font></th>
        <th><font size="-1">Header2</font></th>
        <th><font size="-1">Header3</font></th>
        <th><font size="-1">Header4</font></th> 
        <th><font size="-1">Header5</font></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
function commit(){

    document.menu.cmd.value='search';
    document.menu.submit();       
}
```

When click the button it show the table and again hiding the table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#historylist").hide(); 
$("#historysearch").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $("#historylist").show(); 
    commit(); // moved from the onClick attribute });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#historysearch").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#historylist").show();
    commit(); // moved from the onClick attribute
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: When click the button it show the table and again hiding the table.
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#historylist").hide();
$("#historysearch").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 $("#historylist").show();
commit(); // moved from the onClick attribute
});
});